# Nightwatch switchWindow() not working in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I have a test that cause a new window to open that contains a form to fill out. In FireFox it works to switch to this window using browser.switchWindow(windowName), but in Chrome it does not seem to switch to the window as it is then unable to find the form to fill out in the new window.

Anyone run into anything like this and have a possible solution? Thanks!

Edit:

This is a small code snippet I found showing what I did.

```
browser
  .click('selector') // Button click to open new window
  .pause(1000)
  .switchWindow('newWindowID')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work, for me it was as simple as putting a short pause() before trying to switchWindow(). It seems it tried to switch to the new window before it actually opened.

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave a comment because of not a high enough reputation, but I was wondering if you could show your code for the solution to this.  I am trying to figure out how to get this same scenario to work, and am stumped.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you for updating it!  I ended up getting it to work, but that's great that you followed up.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

if it is not working for some of you, specially in mac machine then try below thing :
Starting with version 75, Chromedriver has W3C Webdriver protocol enabled by default. If you'd like to stick to the JSONWire for now adjust the chromeOptions:

chromeOptions: {
    w3c: false
  }

into nightwatch.json file